# Prestashop Database Error

Tags: database, prestashop-1.6

[image]

I am trying to migrate my website from server to localhost in prestashop. And i have tried following steps.
I assume you’ve configured PHP, Apache and MySQL on your local machine. If you don’t have those things installed, find some informations about how to do it. If you are using Windows I can suggest you installing XAMPP application.

Download all website files from your FTP and put them to the local directory.

Next, let’s export the database from phpMyAdmin to the `.sql` file and download it. Import that file to your local database.

Now it’s a time to make some changes in your local database, files and BackOffice.

Database:

1. Go to the table `PS_SHOP_URL` and change values of following columns:
   – domain localhost
   – domain_ssl localhost
   – If your PrestaShop is located in some addictional directory, set the value of physical_uri (for example, if it’s in the ‘shop’ directory, write /shop/ there)
2. In the `PS_CONFIGURATION` table change the value of `PS_SHOP_DOMAIN` and `PS_SHOP_DOMAIN_SSL`

Files:

1. Set the debug mode ON in `config/defines.inc.php`

`define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true)`
1
`define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true)`
2. Set your local database parameters in `config/settings.inc.php`

3. If your PrestaShop is located in some addictional directory (for example `/shop/`), edit the `.htaccess` file. It’s located in PrestaShop main folder. Add to this part…

`RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:`
1
`RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:`
…that directory. Complete code should look like this:

`RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/shop/`
1
`RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/shop/`
BackOffice:

Advanced Parameters -> Performance
Select “Force compilation” in smarty settings, disable the cache and clear the cache using button located in upper right header of page.

And this sucessfully transfers my site to local host i am able to access backoffice.

but when i access frontoffice there errors as shown in screenshots

Comment: Are you following a document for doing this? A link would be nice.

Comment: http://prestacraft.com/how-to-migrate-prestashop-from-your-web-server-to-local-and-inversely/ ,This is the link

Answer (score 0):

Check in backend under `Preferences->Seo & URLs` the section `Set Shop Url` to see if you have the correct url. As far as I can see in the printscreen, your website is still using the `localhost` url. Also, after checking in the backend, try accessing your website in another browser.

Comment: I want to run my website on local host only. i have checked my backend url it is exactly as it should be (i.e /Imitation45u)

Comment: In ps_configuration set PS_SHOP_DOMAIN_SSL & PS_SHOP_DOMAIN must be set to localhost. Also in ps_shop_url table you must set domain=localhost, domain_ssl=localhost & physical_uri=/imitation45u/

Comment: should i append the - after the folder name of physical_uri, rest of the steps i have followed correctly.